# Digium card shows green and red light after each second after configuration

Tags: voip, asterisk, configure

My digium card and pri was working fine in other system but i removed and installed that digium card in other system .I have configured it but its showing only 24 channels but i have 30 channels .My digium card shows green light then red light then green and than red light and so on.

I have been follwing [this](http://striker24x7.blogspot.in/) tutorial

I tried to reinstall asterisk,dahdi,and configured dahdi many times following above tutorial but it still shows me 24 channels.

the card and pri were worked perfectly in the previous system.

But **what could be the reason of showing 24 channels rather than 30 and changing of card light from green to red the to green  aftersome seconds??**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need configure card as e1,not t1

Comment: I would also add that you should check the manual that came with the card for instructions on how to change the configuration from T1 to E1.

Comment: @arheops i am configuring the card as e1,as mentioned in the tutorial i followed

Comment: if you have 24 channels, that mean you have configured it as t1. Check output of dahdi_cfg -vvv

Comment: ok problem solved,changed the digium card and configured it again then it showed all 30 channels.But i dont know why it happened??